# Get location from photo then use it to place a marker on map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-camera, google-maps-markers

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to grab the location from a photo then use the information to place a marker on my map overlay. Has anyone done this. I dont really know where to being. I will provide the full source to my app if anyone is interested in helping me out. Basically i'd like to make a program that shows a map, and this map displays markers that other users have added. A marker can only be placed from a photo. I have the map set up and how i'd like to call the camera and take the picture, but i'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google Maps as the Map API?

If so then when the picture is taken store the latitude and longitude values in a database (or an array or where ever you please)

Then when the map is viewed show the marker according to those stored locations.

Without more information that is the most I can provide t you at the moment

Regards
RF

Comment: Thanks, Yes i'm using the google maps api. Right now the app opens to my mapview. From there the user can start a new activity, this activity displays a new layout that gives an option to open the camera, once a picture is take via the camera intent the picture is displayed in an image view. I would like for the app to store the information from the camera that contains the photos Lat and Long. Then from there mark those coordinates on the map. Is there more info I could provide?

Comment: When the picture is taken, in the onReceive method (I think its called that- it's basically the method that is returned after the picture is taken) use the Google API to get the user's current location (Lat and Long) and just store that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your "other users" statement, you should see if it's possible to get at the EXIF data stored as metadata in most JPG photos.  This is how the Flickr API allows you to search for photos based on location.  By using EXIF data, you can use any photo, not just the ones taken from your app.  If you do want everything to go through your own app though, you could make a database linking user photos with lat/long information obtained through a `LocationListener`.  Just know the device's location won't be terribly accurate if GPS isn't turned on.